# XCode showing issues in wrong source code line

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am using XCode 6.1.1 and Swift. When I compile my source code and receive compilation errors the first source code line is associated with all errors and painted red, instead of the line on which the error has been detected. Has someone experienced something similar? Is there a solution to show the line on which the error occurred?

Comment: Maybe you could add some hint about the downvote ...

Comment: Maybe you could add the code showcasing the issue, but yes, especially with swift the shown errors are often frustrating.

Comment: Seems to be a general issue, unrelated to a particular code, maybe a bug on XCode. It has shown up in more than one Swift file. The frustating thing is that it wrongly assigns all compiler errors to the first line of the source code. If they were runtime erors I could understand but seems to be something wrong between the compiler and the editor. I have not found a solution by Googling and was wondering if it would be a config issue.

Comment: I would suggest to check the changes at imports, linked frameworks and build settings. It might also be some silly syntax error like a random character somewhere. You might also want to start using any kind of source control tools, even a local repository should help you to see the recent changes and make it easy to roll back or have different branches.

Comment: Thanks. Imports and frameworks are at a minimum for SpriteKit with sound (AVFoundation). I have already scanned build settings, but I will check them again for I have just started using XCode and might have missed something. I am using GitHub from the start, so roll backing is not a problem. The crazy thing is: departing from a code that builds successfully, if I change the name of any given variable, all compiler errors due to that change are presented in line 1 of the source code, regardless of where the changed variable is referenced. That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: If you have a small sample project where one can easily reproduce the issue, you might as well send it to Apple tech support or create a bug report, here at SO people are usually dealing with the compilers as they are.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thank you for your effort in following up with my question. I understand your point regarding people at SO, though I still think the proposed question is not that bad to be down-voted.

Comment: Don't take it personally, the SO might often be confusing but it is still the best at what it does well. Upvoted for cheers up.